# how to toggle a div on button click using "Id"

Tags: vue.js

Below I have written code here I want to toggle a div while we click on this button by using vue.js. By using hidden data property I have tried but I want by using Id="categories" that div should toggle.

```
<button v-on:click="isHidden = !isHidden">categories</button>
```

```
<div id = "categories">While we click on above button I want to toggle this div on button click in vue.js using "Id"</div>
```

```
<script>
    var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    isHidden: false
  }
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the id, just bind `isHidden` to `v-show` directive :

```
<div v-show="isHidden">While we click on above button I want to toggle this div on button click in vue.js using "Id"</div>
```

Comment: but it should toggle while we click on button

Comment: I don't understand